# The equation yields

Tags: traduction, anglais, mathématiques

En anglais on peut dire :

> Substituting equation 6 into equation 5 yields/gives the single equation of motion.

Dans ce contexte tous les deux verbes sont-ils interprétés par donne ?

> La substitution de l'équation 6 à l'équation 5 donne la seule équation de mouvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Une façon naturelle de formuler ça serait:

> En substituant (6) dans (5), on obtient…